# Should I consider [H+] as substrate in MCT transport equation?

Tags: metabolism, cancer, theoretical-biology, membrane-transport, kinetics

I'm trying to model the transport of lactate in cells (in both direction via Monocarboxylate transporters):

**[Lactate]intra + [H+] <----> [Lactate]extra + [H+]**

I found some data on kinetics of Lactate itself (Km and Vmax) but I don't find anything on [H+].

My initial thought was to consider [H+] as a substrate, and model the transport as a sequential ordered Bi-Bi reversible reaction *(from this paper: Poole & Halestrap (1993). Transport of lactate and other monocarboxylates across mammalian plasma membranes. doi:10.1152/ajpcell.1993.264.4.c761)*

But it require a lot of parameters (Ki, Km, Vmax) for each substrate involved (especially H+).

So my question is: Should I consider [H+] as a substrate or just as an external parameter that impact the direction of the flux ?

Thanks everyone

(first question on Stackexchange)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include or exclude the H+ basically depends on the scope of your model. The H+ can be used as external parameters if you assume that both sides of the membrane are well buffered and the pH will not change. If you want to simulate a condition during which the pH changes, like for example strong exercise in muscle or ischemia, then you would need separate H+ for each side of the membrane.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes the pH will change at each side of the membrane (I simulate cancer cells with high glycolytic activity). But if I consider H+ as a substrate like lactate, should it follow a michaelis-menten kinetic (or derivatives) ? If so do you have any idea of where I can find this information about H+ ? I didn't find any paper measuring such parameters for H+.

Comment: I think this [article](https://doi.org/10.1042/bj1960721) can give you some kinetic data on proton symporters with different pH. There is a lot published on the subject but it is difficult to find the best search term... perhaps [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1042/BJ20041519) or [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1529/biophysj.105.073296) may also give some usefull parameters.

Comment: Thank you ! I already downloaded the second article but didn't saw Km values for H+, a second read is usefull :) The cell's paper seems really promising, I'm going to read this right away.